# Encode error in while showing data

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, character-encoding

When i tried to show the data in my view the data rendered was wrong.
**Data**:

```
 "KN\326"
```

and the Output was :

```
KNÖ
```

The data is coming via Viewbag.

Comment: How do you render it on your view ?

Comment: What do you expect? Where is your code? What are you talking about?

Comment: I want the same data("KN\326") to be displayed rather than "KNÖ" in my view.

Comment: @Josel Tried to escape the backslash with another backslash?

Comment: This is not possible because its the data coming from database and it vary in "\". The data is entered by the user and may contain any other special character code in future. Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to escape the " \ ", since \XXX is a special char

Before "printing" it on the screen, juste apply a regex on the string ( `"s/\/\\/g"` could be a correct regex, but i'm not sure)